# How to make a 2 dimensional comparison table in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, restangular

I am working on creating a table similar to a multiplication Table: http://www.eco-pros.com/images/ClipArt-Graphics/multiplication-table.gif for some evaluations.

The data will be coming from the API resource through a REST call using Restangular. Here's the code for the controller after the REST call:

```
getEvaluations.getList("evaluations?searchBy[participant]=880b6fb0-ee34-11e2-a62e-19e0bcac9427").then(function(data){
    evals = data["_embedded"]["items"];

    for (i = 0; i < evals.length; i++){
        allEvals.push({
            rating: evals[i].rating,
            alternative: evals[i]["_embedded"]["alternative"].name,
            criterion: evals[i]["_embedded"]["criterion"].name
        }); 
        /* I'm creating an array of objects to parse the data that comes from the
           resource because the back-end is a bit messy. */

    }
    console.log(allEvals);
    $scope.evaluations = {
        eval: allEvals
    };
    $scope.projectID = $routeParams["projectID"];
}, function error (err){
    alert("Error in fetching resource");
    console.log("error");
});
```

In the view, I've got a table which I have no clue how to fill up.

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-ng-repeat="alternative in alternatives">{{alternative.name}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="criterion in criteria">
            <td><b>{{criterion.description}}</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="{{evaluations.rating}}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the old code for the table where I was using two REST calls to just get the alternative names and the criterion names to populate the table. But I want to be able to use the array of objects I created to populate that instead. And in the input boxes, I want the rating to go there that matches that specific alternative and criterion (so I need something like a conditional statement to check for AA or AB or AC, etc and inject the value for that).

For Example:

> ```
>   A1
> ```
>
> C1  5.0

Any tips or help will be appreciated! Thank you. I'm not sure how to make this question clearer since it's so different.

JS fiddle (not working):

http://jsfiddle.net/GkxeP/8/

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: Got fiddle here but it doesn't seem to work. Sorry, i'm new to all this. http://jsfiddle.net/GkxeP/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final result:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUwXc/1/

---

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do, exactly, but here's what I did to your fiddle:

1. I changed `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`.
2. You had an angular external resource AND angular in the framework - that was causing issues.  So I took out the external resource.
3. In your controller declared an object on the scope called `evaluations` that has a property called `eval`.  In your view, though, you try to call `rating` on `evaluations`.  Your data isn't structured like that.  It looks like you want alternatives in the columns and criterion in the rows, so we need to put your data in a format so that it can be indexed in that fashion.  It's conventional to have rows of columns, so I will make the data be indexed by criterion and then alternative.  To do this I wrote the following:

   ```
   $scope.evaluations = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < allEvals.length; i++) {
       if (!$scope.evaluations.hasOwnProperty(allEvals[i].criterion)) {
           $scope.evaluations[allEvals[i].criterion] = {};
       }

       $scope.evaluations[allEvals[i].criterion][allEvals[i].alternative] = allEvals[i].rating;
   }
   ```

And then in your view:

```
<input id="#{{alternative.id}}" type="text" value="{{evaluations[criterion.name][alternative.name]}}" />
```

Please let me know if you need any more assistance :)